I am Facing the error in the smart contract after setting up the project via command "anchor init project_name --solidity "
The error is in the smart contract of the project setup by anchor init command.
This is the error { " Expected pragma, import directive or contract/interface/library/struct/enum/constant/function/error definition. " }
while in the docs https://solana.com/developers/guides/solang/getting-started  the example smart contact also have the @program_id
but after initializing the project I have encountered this error.
